# How to receive all touch events that occur in a view hierarchy?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, touch

I have a complex view hierarchy controlled by an UIViewController. I'm looking for a simple way to inform the controller about all touches happening inside the hierarchy, even those that *are* handled by subviews. I don't want to intercept them, I just want to be informed about them.

And subclassing all views in the hierarchy is not really an option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass root view in your controller and implement `hitTest:withEvent:` method in it:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    UIView *result = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    // Your custom code
    return result;
}
```